# How to Pass Pointer by Reference in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference

If a subroutine allocates a new buffer, how can the caller of that function pass a pointer to get the address?

Every declaration combination I've tried doesn't work, i.e. after calling the subroutine, the pointer passed does not get set to the address of the buffer created in the subroutine.

```
int main ()
{
   float *fMyBuffer;

   // Pointer Update
   readFloatData ( fMyBuffer ); // &fMyBuffer  *fMyBuffer 

   // Deallocate Memory
   delete [] fMyBuffer;
}


void readFloatData(float *&fBuffer)  //*fBuffer   &fBuffer
{
  // Create New Buffer
  float *fData;
  fData = new float [1000];

  // Pass our buffer Address to user's pointer
  fBuffer = fData;
}
```

Comment: If a reference to a `float` is a `float*`, then a reference to a `float *` is?

Comment: @Sjuan Usually an incredibly bad idea? :-)

Comment: Very simple: 1) function signature: `void readFloatData(float **fBuffer) {...}`, 2) function call: `readFloatData (&fMyBuffer );`, 3) Delete all the (now extraneous) stuff in "readFloatData():.

Comment: The only thing I can see wrong with the code you posted is that you're calling a function before it is declared.

Comment: Thanks, should have mentioned, that for clarity I've ommited some of the details, like the function prototype declaration section.

Also, while its customary that the function return the handle, my actual function needs to return 2 pointer addresses so that's why I wanted to do it as a parameter.   Although, I bet there's a way to return multiple pointers (using vectors/unique_ptrs) however, I'm not very familiar with those types.

Comment: You can always return a throw-away struct: `struct result_type{ float *resultA, *resultB; }; result_type foo() { return (result_type){ .resultA = ... , .resultB = ... }; }`. If you are set on using parameters to return the result by reference, *please* use an explicit pointer: `void foo(float** out_result);` That way, you see at the calling site the `&` operator, which signals that the pointer is about to be changed by the function: `float* result; foo(&result);` looks ok, `float* result; foo(result);` reads like undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually done by passing a double pointer, or the real C++ way is to use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::vector`:

vector:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   std::vector<float> fMyBuffer = readFloatData ();
   return 0;
}


std::vector<float> readFloatData()
{
  // Create New Buffer
  std::vector<float> fData(1000);

  // Populate vector...

  return fData;
}
```

unique_ptr:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   std::unique_ptr<float[]> fMyBuffer = readFloatData (); // Note the [] is MUST else the wrong deleter will be used
   return 0;
}


std::unique_ptr<float[]> readFloatData()
{
  // Create New Buffer
  std::unique_ptr<float[]> fData(new float[1000]);

  // Populate data...

  return fData;
}
```

double pointer:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   float* fMyBuffer = nullptr;
   readFloatData(&fMyBuffer);
   delete[] fMyBuffer;
   return 0;
}


void readFloatData(float** fData)
{
  if (fData)
  {
      // Create New Buffer
      *fData = new float[1000];

     // Populate data...
   }
}
```

And as Konrad Rudolph said, a reference to pointer is possible too:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   float* fMyBuffer = nullptr;
   readFloatData(fMyBuffer);
   delete[] fMyBuffer;
   return 0;
}


void readFloatData(float*& fData)
{
   // Create New Buffer
   fData = new float[1000];
}
```

Note that you can also pass in references to vectors or unique_ptrs, e.g:

```
void readFloatData(std::unique_ptr<float[]>& fData)
void readFloatData(std::vector<float>& fData)
```

Comment: You can also pass a reference to a raw pointer, a thing your answer fails to mention. Thus no need for a double-pointer, either.

Comment: Yeah I guess, I'll add that too

Comment: The reference to a pointer example is what I had in mind,  the fact that there's no explicit assignment is even cooler! 

As several have pointed out, the original code should have worked, but I goofed interpreting the addressing.. the debugger shows the 

fData @0x28fe24: 0x3d6f460
which I took to mean the the buffer is at 0x28fe24... then when the function returned my fMyBuffer pointer was set to 0x3d6f460, not the 0x28Fe24.

Answer (score 1):

Use a double level pointer?

`float **fBuffer` would work just fine.

Comment: You can do that, but you don’t need to.

Comment: Using double pointer is bad advice since its not really idiomatic C++

Answer (score 1):

[Your code actually works as-is](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/848f36202794c6db) (apart from the fact that you need to declare `readFloatData` before using it). The question is whether this is really a good idea – why not return the new value instead? This is what return values are for, after all:

```
float* readFloatData()
{
  // Create New Buffer
  float *fData = new float [1000];

  // Pass our buffer Address to user's pointer
  return fData;
}

int main() {
  float* fMyBuffer = readFloatData();
  // …
  delete [] fMyBuffer;
}
```

That said, raw pointers shouldn’t own memory anyway. Use a `std::unique_ptr` or similar instead. For arrays, use `std::vector<float>` instead of a pointer-to-array.

Comment: That isn't "as-is", exactly.  You've moved things around, which may have been the original problem.

Comment: @Ben Fair point, I’ve amended that. That said, OP’s description definitely sounds like the code compiled and simply did something unexpected. So I’m pretty sure that wasn’t the original problem.